# Largest circle contained in a region delimited by 4 circumferences

Tags: circles, area, geometric-construction

I'm working in a region delimited by 4 circumferences, concentric 2 to 2, with opposite centers (shaded area) which vary with respect to a parameter $\alpha$.

$$r<(x-a(\alpha))^2+y^2<R$$

$$r<(x+a(\alpha))^2+y^2<R$$
[image]

This region is symmetric respect the OY axis.  I would like to obtain the largest circle contained in this region.
What do you think about it? It's possible?

Comment: Are you looking for the largest circle in the intersection, or in the union, of the orange and blue regions?

Comment: In the intersection, the shaded area.

Answer (score 2):

From your nice visualisation, you can see that the desired circle would be tangent to all four circles. For it to be tangent to a pair of concentric circles, its radius must be $\rho=\frac{R-r}2$, and its centre must be at distance $\frac{R+r}2$ from their two centres. Also the centre must clearly lie on the $y$ axis. Its $y$ coordinate can then be obtained from

$$
a(\alpha)^2+y^2=\left(\frac{R+r}2\right)^2
$$

as

$$
y=\sqrt{\left(\frac{R+r}2\right)^2-a(\alpha)^2}\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. One question, then you say that the largest circle has always the same area ($\pi \,\rho^2$)? Independent of $\alpha$?

Comment: @popi: That's true, yes. Consider the extreme cases $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=\frac{R+r}2$. In both cases it's straightforward that the largest circle has radius $\frac{R-r}2$, so it makes sense that this is the case in between, too.